# Retrieve data 'quantmod' package

Tags: r, quantmod, financial

I am trying to retrieve the SP500 data with:

```
SP500 <- getSymbolsundefined"^GSPC", from ="2000-01-01", to = "2016-08-31", auto.assign = FALSE)
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error: unexpected string constant in "SP500 <- getSymbolsundefined"^GSPC""
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, you have a trivial syntax error?  This obviously works:

`SP500 <- getSymbols("^GSPC", from ="2000-01-01", to = "2016-08-31", auto.assign = FALSE)`